# Android Google Maps Info window

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to add multiple markers on map  , and show their info windows at the same time .
When i add the last marker the previous info window markers automatically gets hidden.Can anyone tell me any solution how can i do this?

Comment: Code please... You need to show what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with InfoWindows as noted by the 2nd sentence on [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#introduction). You might try using [this library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) to instead put the text you would be displaying in the InfoWindow in the Marker itself. Be careful with showing too much information on the screen at once, don't want it to get too busy!